# displays undefiend on <p> tag when trying to display a returned value from server side

Tags: javascript

I have a function that scrapes the src of youtube thumbnails and it works fine. The issue starts when I display the scraped src on the client-side both the src of   `thumbnail2` and `thumbnail3` appear as undefined in my `<p>` tags. But when I only return `data1` from the server-side instead of both `data1, data2` it works properly and displays the scraped src on the client-side. I can't figure out what is causing this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrapeChannel2(url) {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url, {
    waitUntil: 'load',
    timeout: 0
  });

  const [el3] = await page.$x('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-browse/ytd-two-column-browse-results-renderer/div[1]/ytd-rich-grid-renderer/div[6]/ytd-rich-item-renderer[1]/div/ytd-rich-grid-media/div[1]/ytd-thumbnail/a/yt-img-shadow/img');
  const src2 = await el3.getProperty('src');
  const thumbnailURL2 = await src2.jsonValue();

  browser.close();
  console.log({
    thumbnailURL2
  })
  return {
    thumbnailURL2
  }
}

async function scrapeChannel3(url) {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url, {
    waitUntil: 'load',
    timeout: 0
  });

  const [el3] = await page.$x('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-browse/ytd-two-column-browse-results-renderer/div[1]/ytd-rich-grid-renderer/div[6]/ytd-rich-item-renderer[1]/div/ytd-rich-grid-media/div[1]/ytd-thumbnail/a/yt-img-shadow/img');
  const src3 = await el3.getProperty('src');
  const thumbnailURL3 = await src3.jsonValue();

  browser.close();
  console.log({
    thumbnailURL3
  })
  return {
    thumbnailURL3
  }
}

async function callscrapeChannel() {
  const data1 = await scrapeChannel2('https://www.youtube.com/')
  const data2 = await scrapeChannel3('https://www.youtube.com/')
  return {
    data1,
    data2
  };
}
callscrapeChannel()
module.exports = {
  callscrapeChannel,
}
```

```html
<p id="avatarUrlId1" style="color: white;"></p>
<p id="avatarUrlId2" style="color: white;"></p>

<script>
  async function callScrapeData() {
    await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/scrapedata`)
      .then((res) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(res.json())
          }, 1000)
        })

      }).then((response) => {
          console.log(response)

          document.getElementById("avatarUrlId1").innerHTML = response.thumbnailURL2

          document.getElementById("avatarUrlId2").innerHTML = response.thumbnailURL3

        }

      )
  }
</script>

<button onclick="callScrapeData()">click</button>
```

Comment: `return {
    data1,
    data2
  };`
    This line will return your response as `{ data1: 'src', data2: 'src' }` you need to use spread operator for merging the two responses into one object i.e.,  `{...data1, ...data2}`

Comment: What you mean by changing it to `data1`? What is your end response that you want? `{thumbnailURL3: 'src'}` or `{data1: {thumbnailURL3: 'src'}}` ? Currently your code is returning the 2nd response

Comment: That fixed it. Can you please add it as an answer. Thanks for the help!@BeshambherChaukhwan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return {
  data1,
  data2
};
```

This line will return your response as `{ data1: {thumbnailURL2: 'src'} , data2: {thumbnailURL3: 'src'} }` you need to use spread operator for merging the two responses into one object i.e.,

```
return { ...data1, ...data2 };
```